# border-radius and IE 7 and IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, css3pie

I am applying border-radius on my layout and I having problems with IE 7 and IE8. I'm using the PIE.htc but I still can not do the compatibility works.

The code is:

```
border-top-left-radius: 4px;
border-top-right-radius: 4px;
border-top: 0;          

-moz-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px; 
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
```

I'm testing in ieTester, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. if you use `behavior: url(PIE.htc);` then your `Pie.htc` should be in the same folder as your html page or master page.
2. your page's doctype should be XHTML or HTML5.
3. then my experience says its better to place the behavior code on top your css rule.
4. you better not use IE Tester as a trustful utility. It came up with a  hand full of tools but not quite useful ones. its better to use IE 9, then change its browser and document mode in its developer tools. when you change them the whole page will reload in that mode. it even has quirk mode which is a complete total NIGHTMARE.

   And if you can update your question with more facts about your code and browser.