# datatable plugin not working in mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

This is my day one with jQuery. I am using Data Table to display data in my HTML table. 
I am using the following config options.

```
$("#myTable_id").dataTable({
             "bJQueryUI": true,
             "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
});
```

I am able to see the paging details, but I am unable to see the proper UI like in the third screenshot in the link below (though I have used bJQueryUI: true). 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/194916/Enhancing-HTML-tables-using-a-JQuery-DataTables-pl#Introduction

I learn that ThemeRoller is used to accomplish this (http://datatables.net/usage/features). Should I download and include ThemeRoller related files in project or does dataTable plugin internally contains ThemeRoller's code and style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include Jquery ui standard .css file in your documnet.
where it can understand what to show you.
alternatively you can use themeroller to make your desired css file
you can find the .css file in [jqueryui.com](http://jqueryui.com)

jqueryui works well in ie9+ but you can not have some items like round corners or background gradient in ie8- .
first check your ie version, and if you want a complete compatible site with ie8-, then you should use some plugins like `css3 pie`, but i don't advice that,
   you can find a some clues in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13689618/border-radius-and-ie-7-and-ie8/14268875#14268875)

Comment: thanks, its working well in chrome and firefox but not working internet explorer,can u tell me compatability solution...

Comment: thanks for ur great information,i added pie.htc for my corner radius,but even it is not working in IE8..

Comment: there may be many situations in it put your code here and share it to me in another question and i will answer it for you

Comment: am getting only first 10 entries even i have more data,paginations buttons are in disable mode only...

Comment: sorry didn't understand ur last comment

Comment: iam using datatable plugin which i mentioned in starting,in that we have option of showing entries 10,25,50,100.but am getting only first 10 entries even i mentioned to show 25 entries in the datatable